# Qt GLWidget in GraphicsScene for fast video display from image data (C++ , Windows)?

Tags: image, qt, opengl, video

There are a few questions about displaying video more efficiently in Qt than by showing it as QLabel. There seem to be two approaches:

- Write directly to a window's / widget's image buffer (but I could not find information whether this is possible with Qt, while MSVC / MSC applications apparently can write to a window handle)
- Use OpenGL to display via hardware

  - [Image scaling (KeepAspectRatioByExpanding) through OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011108/image-scaling-keepaspectratiobyexpanding-through-opengl)
  - [What is the most efficient way to display decoded video frames in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242005/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-display-decoded-video-frames-in-qt)

Since my current approach involves a QPixmapItem created from a QImage populated with my image data, even at small resulutions (<1 MP, 30 Hz) my Core2Duo is reporting 40 % load.

I would like to keep using QGraphicsScene in order to show multiple images/videos, but I don't know whether it's possible to show (multiple) QGLWidgets in a scene - is it?

Comment: The Qt documentation for [QGraphicsScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) states that adding a QGLWidget is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not several GLWidget, but several GraphicsItem, calling `painter->beginNativePainting`which allows openGL commands to be issued.

The **viewport** of the graphicView must be a QGLwidget, the latter initialized with QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers) in the constructor.
see [Qt widgets using opengl](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html)

The case is simpler when OpenGL active item is in the background, because calls to glClear  erase the viewport background as well, clearing any item below with a lower zorder.